# Repeat index by giving list

Tags: python, list, indexing, csr

Not sure if this kind of question is exist or not. If so, I will delete the post later.

I tried to build a list with repeating index which will follow the list here:

`Mylist = [3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]`

My output should be:

`expect = [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]`

The index will change when the value in the giving list changes.

I tried the code like this:

```
z_pts = [0] * (len(z_rows)) 
i_cur = -1
for k in range(len(z_rows)):  
    if z_rows[k] != i_cur:                
       i_cur = z_rows[k]         
       z_pts[i_cur] = k
```

However, I only could get result like this:

`res = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0]`

Comment: How exactly do you get from `Mylist` to `expect`? I'm not following.

Comment: Is "*giving list*" something that a user inputs?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. So the values of the expected list are the index of the first occurrence of the initial list.

Comment: My apologies for the unclear post. The list can be anything with duplicated values, and the same values won't be separate from the list. I want to know how to get a new list by their index of the first occurrence of the initial list like what @B Remmelzwaal said.

Comment: What does *"the same values won't be separate from the list"* mean?

Comment: For example, list will be [1,1,2,2,3,3,3], but won't be [1,2,1,3,3,2,3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very simply using a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```
my_list = [3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]

new_list = [my_list.index(i) for i in my_list]

print(new_list) # [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Or `new_list = [*map(my_list.index, my_list)]`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
lst = [3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]

tmp = 0, -1
out = [tmp[0] if tmp[1] == t[1] else (tmp := t)[0] for t in enumerate(lst)]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Clever use of enumerate!

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way to do it but with only built-ins I got the answer with this:

```py
Mylist = [3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
expect = [0]

for i, n in enumerate(Mylist[1:], 1):
    expect.append(expect[i-1] if n == Mylist[i-1] else i)

print(expect)
```

Output:

```py
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
```